# Back-reference in Spark DataFrame `regexp_replace`

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, backreference

I was recently trying to answer a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146760/splitting-row-in-multiple-row-in-spark-shell/40148915#40148915), when I realised I didn't know how to use a back-reference in a regexp with Spark DataFrames.

For instance, with sed, I could do

```
> echo 'a1
b22
333' | sed "s/\([0-9][0-9]*\)/;\1/"                                                                                                   

a;1
b;22
;333
```

But with Spark DataFrames I can't:

```
val df = List("a1","b22","333").toDF("str")
df.show

+---+
|str|
+---+
| a1|
|b22|
|333|
+---+

val res = df  .withColumn("repBackRef",regexp_replace('str,"(\\d+)$",";\\1"))
res.show

+---+-----------+
|str|repBackRef|
+---+----------+
| a1|       a;1|
|b22|       b;1|
|333|        ;1|
+---+----------+
```

Just to make it clear: I don't want the result in this particular case, I would like a solution that would be as generic as back reference in, for instance, `sed`.

Note also that using `regexp_extract` is lacking since it behaves badly when no matching:

```
val res2 = df
  .withColumn("repExtract",regexp_extract('str,"^([A-z])+?(\\d+)$",2))
res2.show
```

So that you are forced to use one column per pattern to extract as I did in the said [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146760/splitting-row-in-multiple-row-in-spark-shell/40148915#40148915).

Thanks!

Comment: yes! Thanks! I looked for such a trivial syntax thing like this but I didn't find it. I'll accept if you put it in answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the `$`+`numeric_ID` backreference syntax:

```
.withColumn("repBackRef",regexp_replace('str,"(\\d+)$",";$1"))
                                                         ^^
```